# Mac OS X Lion cannot resolve localhost

Tags: macos, localhost, hosts

I have found serval questions about this but no one helps for me, I am searching for
days to get my problem solved but I can't get it done, I hope someone can help
me with this big issue.

I try to ping my localhost, I need this to develop my web apps. I do this by zendServer.

This problem cames up when I upgraded my OS X to Lion.

I use internet over Apple timecapsule but I think this doesn't matter to make it able to use your localhost?

Host file (sudo nano /private/etc/hosts):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Dig result:

```
leny-pc:~ nickyklaasse$ dig localhost

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> localhost
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18908
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;localhost.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
localhost.      10800   IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.254#53(192.168.1.254)
;; WHEN: Thu Dec  1 13:08:07 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

Host result:

```
leny-pc:~ nickyklaasse$ host localhost
localhost has address 127.0.0.1
localhost has IPv6 address ::1
```

Ping result:

```
leny-pc:~ nickyklaasse$ ping localhost
ping: cannot resolve localhost: Unknown host
```

I hope some one can help me to an answer.

With kind regards,

Nicky

Comment: you might have better luck if you look on [su] -- for example, I saw a great number of hits [when I did a search on /etc/hosts](http://superuser.com/search?q=%22%2Fetc%2Fhosts%22+macintosh&submit=search)

Comment: I'm having the same problem since updating to Lion. It must have something to do with Web Sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by a clean new installation of Mac Os Lion by DVD

Answer (score 0):

Comment this 2 lines and try again:

```
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

and let me know what happen

Comment: Thank you for the fast reaction, I comment out those two lines and did a 'dscacheutil -flushcache', did also a reboot but it makes no sense. (I still cant ping localhost)